# ASP.Net MVC3 - Linq to SQL or Stored procedures?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-sql, stored-procedures

I am new to MVC3 and I have been using Linq to SQL and stored procedures till now for my applications. I am ambiguous whether to go  with Linq to SQL or traditional stored procedures.
I have seen a blog here,
http://weblogs.asp.net/jalpeshpvadgama/archive/2011/06/20/petapoco-with-stored-procedures.aspx
where the stored procedure is used inside the entity framework model.

But am not sure which would be the best way for the MVC3 applications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overview of two approaches:

**Linq to Sql:**

Linq to Sql builds sql for you. You can tell approximately what your sql is going to look like, but if you get a more complex call to DB it becomes harder to control what the outcome sql will be for performance purposes.

It is possible to view generated Sql code as per this [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386961.aspx), however tuning your sql will become a bit of a hassle since you have to run your code in order to view generated sql.

**PetaPoco:**

With PetaPoco (see full [documentation](http://www.toptensoftware.com/petapoco/)) you still can use entities to update your tables (useful for simple crud operations). In addition you can simply throw a stored procedure name to it, which will allow you to concentrate on your SQL code in SQL Server Management Studio allowing easy tuning.

**My opinion:**

I find it is more convenient to use PetaPoco rather than Linq to Sql because you get better control of your sql code.

There are also some performance [considerations](http://www.toptensoftware.com/Articles/95/Benchmarking-SubSonic-s-Slow-Performance). PetaPoco seems to be faster.

Answer (score 0):

There is no 'best way for MVC3 applications'. It depends entirely on your application's requirements and your own taste.

There's a wide range of solutions from hand coded queries to micro ORMs like PetaPoco and Dapper and full ORMs with all the bells and whistles you can think of like nHibernate and Entity Framework.

The best solution for your application is most likely a mix of these though. I've found that for most of the common data access scenario's an ORM works well. If you require more performance or control over your queries, Micro ORMs are the way to go. You can mix and match as you like.

You may find this [blog post on StackOverflow's data access strategy](http://samsaffron.com/archive/2011/03/30/How+I+learned+to+stop+worrying+and+write+my+own+ORM) an interesting read.